# Deserialize XML node with Underscore is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have following XML file, and I am trying to deserialize it. It is working fine for the `<Shape>` node, but for first node I am getting NULL always, I am not sure it is because of underscore (`_`).

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
    <TestData>
        <Test_x0020_Id>P123</Test_x0020_Id>
        <Shape>ROUND</Shape>
    </TestData>
</Test1>
```

Code :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestData>), new XmlRootAttribute("Test1"));

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(content);

List<TestData> productList = (List<TestData>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

public class TestData
{
    [XmlElement("Test_x0020_Id")]
    public string Testx0020Id{ get; set; }
    public string Shape { get; set; }
}
```

Now for `Shape` I am getting proper values, but for `Test_x0020_Id` I am getting NULL every time..

Any ideas on this?

Comment: U+0020 is the space character. It was serialized from something that has a space in the name, so the space was encodeded as `_x0020_` in the element name.  Maybe `[XmlElement("Test Id")]` will do it?

Comment: it's not working

Comment: your root-element in your xml is `Test1`, not `List<Testdata>`(which by the way cannot be used as root-element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this Xml Element Name.

```
[XmlElement("Test Id")]
public string Test_x0020_Id {get; set;}
```